# How do I trigger a Hangfire job manually?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, hangfire

The idea is, on a loading page, there is an email input field. Once the user writes his email and clicks the Get Email button, a background job should trigger. It will check if the transaction is complete, and once it is, it will send an email to the user. All the necessary code regarding the email service (I used `mailgun`) is already written, but I am completely lost on how to implement the scheduler.

How should I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `Enqueue` to trigger job manually

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!"));
```

**@EDIT**

To run second job, if first was succesfull you can use `ContinueWith()`

```
var id = BackgroundJob.Enqueue<ITask1>(x => Console.WriteLine("First task")); 
if (id != null) 
{ 
    BackgroundJob.ContinueWith<ITask2>(id, x => Console.WriteLine("Second task")); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Quick question, how would I get it to return a true/false value. I want the child job to begin once the parent job has returned "true"

Answer (score 4):

For anyone landing here looking to manually trigger/enqueue a scheduled job (like i did):

```
_backgroundJobs.ChangeState(jobId, new EnqueuedState(), ScheduledState.StateName);
```

Where `_backgroundJobs` is an implementation of `IBackgroundJobClient` injected using an IoC container.

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by @shikyo did not work for me on Hangfire 1.7.27. However, this did:

```
IRecurringJobManager.Trigger(HangfireRecurringJobID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can this

```
RecurringJob.TriggerJob
```

Comment: Hi @LemonNoCry, welcome to the stack! This question already has several well validated answers. Could you please explain your solution and what it adds that other existing answers do not cover?